# Download file just uploaded with html input file

Tags: javascript, html, file

I have classic HTML input type for file

```
<input type="file" id="xxx" name="xxx" />
```

And I want the user to have an option to download back the file he just uploaded.

I tried to do it with javascript to download via filepath, but chrome seems to have some security feature that replaces the real path with "fakepath"

> C:\fakepath\xxx.pdf

Any idea how to download the uploaded file (just client side, not submitting the form yet) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery/Javascript upload and download a file without a backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21230012/jquery-javascript-upload-and-download-a-file-without-a-backend)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [URL.createObjectURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) to create a link that allows the user to download the file.

```js
const input = document.getElementById('upload');
const link = document.getElementById('link');
let objectURL;

input.addEventListener('change', function () {
  if (objectURL) {
    // revoke the old object url to avoid using more memory than needed
    URL.revokeObjectURL(objectURL);  
  }

  const file = this.files[0];
  objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);

  link.download = file.name; // this name is used when the user downloads the file
  link.href = objectURL;
});
```

```html
<input type="file" id="upload" />
<a id="link" download>link to your file (upload a file first)</a>
```

*Note on the snippet:* The browser may block doing multiple downloads this way.

Answer (score 2):

This is the same snippet from above, with 2 improvements:

- Download link is not visible
- Download starts automatically (if not blocked by browser)

Filename is still not getting taken

```js
const input = document.getElementById('upload');
const link = document.getElementById('link');
let objectURL;

input.addEventListener('change', function () {
  if (objectURL) {
    // revoke the old object url to avoid using more memory than needed
    URL.revokeObjectURL(objectURL);  
  }

  const file = this.files[0];
  objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);

  link.href = objectURL;
  link.click();
});
```

```html
<input type="file" id="upload" />
<a id="link" download style="display: none">shouldnt be visible</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can download file using **URL.createObjectURL()** function, `<a>` and `<button>` element in the following way

```
const data = {
  lastModified: 1701069121191,
  lastModifiedDate: Mon Nov 27 2023 12:42:01 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) {},
  name: "Template_v2(1).xlsx",
  size: 91827,
  type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
  webkitRelativePath: ""
}

const onDownload = d => {
    const link = document.createElement('a')
    link.download = d.name
    link.href = URL.createObjectURL(d) // method creates a string containing a URL representing the object
    link.click()
}

<button onClick={onDownload(data)} variant="contained" color="primary">Download</button>
```