# upload a file inUI in the UI Browser If the user wants to check the file should be able to download it

Tags: javascript, jquery-file-upload

Hi I am using the #myfile to select the file to upload it in the backend but before uploading it in the db or server i want to download it and check whether it is the same file or not so how can i download the file I am using formData to store the file data using JavaScript .

Comment: Would you be able to provide a sample of your existing code?

Comment: This question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57953389/download-file-just-uploaded-with-html-input-file